# How to check if string is null in c#.net

Tags: c#, string, file, nul

I am reading text file in c#.net 
at the end one line is completely null but in foreach c# can not detect null string so It gets error

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dir);
List<KeyValuePair<int, DateTime>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, DateTime>>();
List<KeyValuePair<int, DateTime>> lst = new List<KeyValuePair<int, DateTime>>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line!=string.Empty)
    {
        l = line.Split('\t');
        l[0] = l[0].Trim();
        PersianCalendar persCal = new PersianCalendar();
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
        SqlCommand sqlda = new SqlCommand("InsertReadd", sqlconn);
        sqlda.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", l[1]);
        sqlda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDp", l[0]);
        sqlda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", GetDayOfWeek(GetPerDate(l[1])));
        sqlda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nobatkari", "");
        sqlda.Connection.Open();
        sqlda.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlda.Connection.Close();
    }
}
RefGrid();
```

Comment: are you looking for `String.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: You should include what error you actually get.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`  is a good choice

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
```

just do this and it works

It checks for Null and Empty. This is the used everywhere for this functionality in C#.

**EDIT:**
You can use the following for checking strings which contains whitespaces.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
```

Comment: I test it .it doesnot work

Comment: @javad please show the error u get

Comment: I get no error but when line is empty it passes from if clause

Comment: @javad I guess the line is full of Whitespaces. Can you confirm. Please give a clear idea. I will solve it

Comment: Yes that's true.the line is full of Whitespaces,I am reading lines of a text file with foreach loop

Comment: @see my updated code. hope It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

[CHECK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

change:

```
 if (line!=string.Empty)
```

to:

```
  //check if the sting = null or empty
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
  { 
     //some code 
  }
```